# How to persist a particular orientation for webview ?

Tags: android, webview, android-orientation

I'm currently working on a payment screen in a kiosk model app on a tablet. The app is in landscape mode. However, when I try to complete the payment ( I have integrated Payumoney for this ), the orientation of the app changes automatically to portrait mode. My assumption is that it redirects to some other webview. Is there any way to handle the orientation or persist the orientation state of the app even in a webview.

Comment: Currently, my app is in "landscape" mode. I need to persist the same orientation in every case. For the webview also. I have added the orientation as "landscape" in the manifest of each activity. still no help

Comment: where is your `webview` launched from? is it from your `code` or from the `payment sdk`, if its from the sdk, the sdk might want you to view it in `portrait` mode

Comment: It is from the payment SDK itself. Yes, and I think they want to view it in the "portrait mode" itself. Is there any other way to override that case? or can we override the webview with another layout or something like that?

Comment: simple workaround for this would be to design your app to adapt with tablets, so that the issue with `portrait/landscape` mode doesn't matter any more

Answer (score 0):

Try anyone of these solutions.

1. In your activity tag of manifest file

   ```
   <activity
       ....
       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       ....
   <activity>
   ```
2. If you want to handle it programmatically then you can also implement `onConfigurationChanged` method in your activity class. This method is called whenever there is configuration changes.
   For more information on configuration changes refer to this [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).
   Hope it helps.